# Cannot get decimal entries from array to appear in listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

In my VB class we've been asked to set up an array which is populated by user entries. These entries are decimal type, meant to be gas prices. There are twelve, one per month. The entries are supposed to show up one at a time, as they are entered and processed, in a list box.

I've got them showing up but they're not showing up properly. Instead of 4.55 (or whatever), the entries show up as "Decimal[] Array" (minus the quotation marks, of course).

How can I get the entries to show up properly? The code is below and it's very incomplete as I'm only about a third of the way into the project, so don't sweat that unless you see some horrible problem sticking out like a sore thumb.

```
Public Class GasPrices
Dim prices(11) As Decimal

Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click
    prices(PriceList.Items.Count) = Convert.ToDecimal(PriceText.Text)
    PriceText.Clear()

    For i = 0 To 11
        prices(i) = i
    Next i

    PriceList.Items.Add(prices)

End Sub

Private Sub PriceList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PriceList.SelectedIndexChanged
    PriceList.Items.Clear()
    PriceList.Items.Add(prices)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the entire array as one "entry".  You'd need to add each individual entry instead using syntax like you've got where you access `prices(i)` in the loop.

```
Public Class GasPrices

    Private prices(11) As Decimal

    Private Sub EnterButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles EnterButton.Click
        If PriceList.Items.Count < 12 Then
            Dim price As Decimal
            If Decimal.TryParse(PriceText.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency, Nothing, price) Then
                prices(PriceList.Items.Count) = price
                PriceList.Items.Add(price)

                PriceText.Clear()
                PriceText.Focus()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Price!")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("12 entries have already been entered!")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub PriceList_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles PriceList.SelectedIndexChanged
        If PriceList.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
            Label1.Text = PriceList.SelectedItem
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I feel like that might be a little funky for the instructor, since we haven't done datasource manipulation.

Let me see if I follow your initial suggestion though. You're saying do something like this?

prices(0) = PriceText.Text
prices(1) = PriceText.Text

etc?

Comment: Gotcha...try something more like the above then.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple. With `Add` you add the array itself as single object to the listbox. The listbox's default behavior is to show `object.ToString` for each entry. And since the object is an array of decimals, you get the unwanted output.

If you want to add the `elements` of an array to a list, listbox, ... you use the `AddRange` method instead.

Comment: When I attempted this: **PriceList.Items.AddRange(prices)**  

I receive this:  

'Error 1 Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Sub AddRange(items() As Object)': Value of type '1-dimensional array of Decimal' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of Object' because 'Decimal' is not a reference type.
    'Public Sub AddRange(value As System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection)': Value of type '1-dimensional array of Decimal' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection'.'